# get empty list when parsing instagram following with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, instagram

I'm trying to make a program to get a list of following on instagram. Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_html(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return response.text

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    fol = soup.find_all('a', class_='_2g7d5')
    print(fol)

parse(get_html('https://www.instagram.com/any_user/following/'))
```

But I get an empty list as a result. The code works correctly, when parsing any other website. What's wrong?
P.S. the class has a really weird name

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work because, you'll need to be a valid authorized user of instagram to access that. In your code, there is no authentication happening. So, from instagram's Point of View, you're just a ghost trying to access their data. So they don't let you in. Google for some 3rd party python wrappers that use instagram wrappers.

First google search led me [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram).
Also, you can't scrape websites like that. It is illegal to be honest. You need to use their developer API with a valid token.